# How to expand text or snippet with the help of HammerSpoon?

Tags: macos, lua, hammerspoon

Can we use `HammerSpoon` to expand text just like aText or TextExpander ?

There is `hs.eventtap.keyStrokes("asdf")` but how to detect the keystroke and expand the text?

E.g. One use case is to expand `mme` -> `myemail@address.com`.

How to achieve this with HammerSpoon ?

Answer (score 1):

The very nice, open source Spoon (a HammerSpoon plugin/library) called HammerText is the solution here. However, it's not perfect because the solution randomly stops working after some time and nobody knows why - probably a HammerSpoon bug.

https://gist.github.com/maxandersen/d09ebef333b0c7b7f947420e2a7bbbf5#file-init-lua

For good measure, the example you've given does not require HammerText, aText or TextExpander, just plain Mac System Preferences > Keyboard > Text replacement.